# Plotting 2D scalar velocity field with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe which I'm trying to plot,

```
x,y,u,v
-0.157806993154554,-0.05,0.000601310515776,0.003318849951029
-0.374687807296859,-0.35,-0.001057069515809,2.9686838388443E-05
-1,-0.323693574077183,-0.002539682900533,-0.008748378604651
-0.486242955499287,-0.35,-0.001797694480047,0.000218112021685
-0.54184300562917,-0.05,0.001513708615676,0.001884449273348
0,-0.31108016382718,5.28732780367136E-05,-0.000818025320768
-0.428046308037431,-0.35,-0.001458290731534,8.22432339191437E-05
-0.343159653530217,-0.05,0.00112508633174,0.002580288797617
-0.386254219645565,-0.35,-0.001139726256952,2.6945024728775E-05
-0.600252053226546,-0.05,0.001246933126822,0.00207519903779
-1,-0.061575842243108,-0.000705834245309,0.043682213872671
0,-0.052056831172645,0.009899478405714,-0.003894355148077
-0.903283837058102,-0.35,5.81557396799326E-05,-0.001065131276846
-0.418202966058798,-0.05,0.001158628845587,0.002409461885691
-0.809266339501268,-0.35,0.000290673458949,-2.0977109670639E-05
0,-0.066616962597653,2.92772892862558E-05,0.001737955957651
-0.090282152608,-0.35,0.00151876010932,0.001403901726007
-1,-0.173440678035212,-0.007741978392005,0.006023477762938
-1,-0.155079864747918,-0.00761691480875,0.007886063307524
-0.222728396757266,-0.35,0.000686463201419,0.000264558941126
```

where u,v and x,y are positional coordinates and the velocity vectors at that point. (full dataset - https://pastebin.pl/view/0f60b48e)

I want to plot my data like so (Contour lines and arrows are not required.) [image: velocity field plots].

How do I do this?

So far I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
# Meshgrid
#x, y = np.meshgrid(box_df['x'], box_df['y'])
x,y = box_df['x'], box_df['y']
  
# Directional vectors

#u, v = np.meshgrid(box_df['u'], box_df['v'])
u = box_df['u']
v = box_df['v']
  
# Plotting Vector Field with QUIVER
plt.quiver(x, y, u, v, color='g')
plt.title('Vector Field')
  
  
# Show plot with gird
plt.grid()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to plot a scalar field with irregular data points, you can either [interpolate between data points to form a regular grid](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html), or you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour.html?highlight=tricontour#matplotlib.pyplot.tricontour) and `tricontourf` to interpolate for you to fill.

Using `tricontour` you could try:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = box_df.x, box_df.y
  
# make scalar field
speed = np.hypot(box_df.u, box_df.v)
  
# Plotting scalar field with tricontour
plt.tricontourf(x, y, speed)
plt.title('Scalar Field')
  
# Show plot with gird
plt.grid()
```

[image]

However it appears that you only have data around the edge of a rectangle, so interpolation into the interior of the rectangle is likely to be poor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks like something not quite right my the way I've exported data